# Why do we use [H⁺] and [OH⁻] in balancing redox reactions instead of using [H₃O⁺] and [OH⁻]?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, aqueous-solution, notation, protons

For what reason is it universally agreed upon that we use $$\ce{H+ + OH-}$$ ions in balancing water on either side of the reaction, but not the $$\ce{H3O+}$$ ions?

Comment: Who said hydronium isn't used? You can use either $\ce{H+}$ or $\ce{H3O+}$ or even $\ce{H9O4+}$ — it just adds complexity in terms of bloated stoichiometry. So, if you don't want to focus on what business does a proton have in aqueous solution, in most cases you get away with $\ce{H+}$ just fine.

Comment: @andselisk so basically it's because of the accuracy and complexity of which we want to refer to when doing redox reactions?

Comment: "on average, each hydronium ion is solvated by 6 water molecules which are unable to solvate other solute molecules."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydronium#Solvation

Comment: @user243851 Yes, I suppose you can put it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is by far not universally agreed upon. My year 10 chemistry teacher taught me to use $\ce{H3O+}$ in balancing. The result is a larger number of water molecules on the other side of the equation but everything else is the same.

Many chemists will prefer $\ce{H+}$ because it is shorter and simpler, that’s all.

Answer (score 0):

Because what we really need to know here is the concentration of *protons*. The concentration of water is considered to be constant in most of the calculations involving the water autodissociation. Thus, you may hydrate the said *proton* in your equation however you want — or not at all — but $K_\mathrm{w} = [\ce{H+}][\ce{OH-}]$ would still be equal to $K_\mathrm{w} = [\ce{H9O4+}][\ce{OH-}]$ and, well, who needs extra complications?